# Setting Control.Capture = true hides the cursor

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse

When I set my control's `Capture` property to true, I receive the mouse events like I expect, but the cursor becomes invisible. Is this expected behavior, and if so, how can I make the cursor displayed when I am capturing it?

Sample Code:

This assumes you have a `Form` with a `TextBox` which has the `TextChanged` event linked appropriately.

Now, the sample code is really for the case of `(Form).Capture` to keep the sample code short, but I've tested it already and it also causes my mouse to disappear.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Capture = true;
    }
}
```

Type something in the text box and the mouse will disappear.

Comment: There's no correlation between mouse capture and visibility.  Post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Sample code posted.

Comment: Yah, don't do that. Boil 25 years of appcompat hacks with the "hide mouse cursor while typing" option and you'll get something green that will eat your lunch like that.

Comment: I'm not trying to hide it, I don't want it hidden. I wanted to know what to do to make it appear again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse capture interrupts the normal flow of mouse processing which includes setting the cursor, so you should manually set the cursor.

Comment: This seems to fix the problem. Thank you!

Comment: What code did you use to set the cursor? please clarify.